# Como impedir que um formulário seja recarregado ao atualizar a página do navegador?

Tags: php, request

Tenho um formulário com a seguinte estrutura abaixo:

```
<?php
     //Lógica em php....
?>
<html>
.....
<form method="post" action="">
.....
<input type="submit">
.....
```

Ao clicar no botão de submit a página recarrega, executando no servidor a lógica php e retornando o resultado para a própria página. Entretanto, ao recarregar o navegador (F5 por exemplo) o mesmo pergunta se desejo recarregar a requisição. Existe uma forma de impedir que o navegador obrigue ao cliente a sempre recarregar a último requisição?

Obs.: Sei que existem maneiras simples de resolver este problema, como a utilização de Ajax. Mas a ideia aqui é resolver este problema sem alterar a estrutura atual. Isto é possível?

Comment: Não entendi  bem sua pergunta, mas se você quiser enviar os dados do formulario sem  atualizar a pagina você pode fazer o submit do form em um iframe usando o target,  ou  usar o  ajax do Jquery, caso você queira "manter os dados do formulario" ao atualizar a pagina você pode salva-los em cookies em  javascript ou em SESSION no  servidor(ai vai depender da linguagem que servidor está usando)

Answer (score -2):

Veja bem, eu vou sugerir uma forma simples de você resolver isso sem alterar a estrutura, mas eu desaconselho qualquer solução que mantenha essa estrutura, porque está utilizando lógica de negócio junto da sua View, entre outros detalhes. Então em seguida vou te sugerir uma melhor, que vai te dar mais liberdade de modificações futuras, e não é complicada.

Forma 1) Inicie uma sessão na página, encapsule todo sem código em um if(!$_SESSION['...']), e após o if inicie sua session.

```
session_start();
if(!$_SESSION['pass']){ 
   ...
}
$_SESSION['pass'] = true;
```

O usuário vai passar pelo bloco IF uma vez, porque a sessão 'pass' não foi criada, mas não vai passar duas vezes porque ela foi criada assim que passou pelo bloco de código. Você pode variar essa solução, adicionar outros validadores e etc.

Forma 2) Retire todo esse código PHP e mova-o para uma página exclusiva(como um script) onde o irá lidar somente com PHP. Aponte o formulário para este script, e no final dela redirecione o usuário para o formulário novamente. Ainda não é a melhor forma de fazer mas é bem mais eficiente de como está sendo feita.

Um abraço e boa sorte.

Comment: O problema de método 1 é que isto iria bloquear de forma permanente a execução da lógica. Ex: Digamos que o usuário execute o formulário. Ao recarregar a página a lógica não será executada. Mas como este controle está sendo feito por uma sessão, se ele ir para outra página e voltar para está, a lógica não será executada novamente ao menos que eu faça uma nova verificação em outras páginas do projeto.

Comment: O método 2, não funcionaria pois altera a regra de não alterarmos a estrutura. Lembrando que está questão não irá solucionar um problema real. Eu a trouxe para o Stahl Overflow como uma forma de debate. As vezes podemos encontrar situações como está em sistemas legado. Imagine uma lógica com trinta mil linhas. Neste caso, uma alternativa pode ser melhor que separa os arquivos, pois trará menos impacto ao código legado.

Comment: Ah, ok, imaginei que era essa a sua intenção, executar apenas uma única vez.

Answer (score -3):

Isso funcionou pra mim. No F5, o md5 do POST não muda. Dai usamos essa brecha para identificar se o submit é real ou só refresh.

```
  if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' )
    {
        $request = md5( implode( $_POST));

        if( isset( $_SESSION['last_request'] ) && $_SESSION['last_request'] 
== $request)
        {
        $caso = 'BEM_VINDO';
    }
    else
    {
```

Comment: Vou testar está solução

Comment: E se for preciso enviar as mesmas informações uma segunda vez, não através da atualização da página? Isso bloqueará de ser feito, sem contar que é gambiarra. Idealmente uma resposta HTTP ao post não deveria possuir um corpo HTML, mas sim redirecionar com o cabeçalho *Location* para o novo recurso criado.